# phpMyAdmin installation between the two web servers

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, localhost

Not very sure I understood the problem in detail.Please let me explain step by step.

I setup two web servers and one at my PC and another one at AWS EC2 instance.
I installed phpmyadmin for localhost. I can access my phpmyadmin at localhost and setup database and web application at localhost.

When I tried to install phpmyadmin at AWS EC2 instance, installation is fine.
But access to the phpmyadmin has problem and always have 403 Forbidden error.
That error is always because of right ip address issue at /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf file.

The problem is there. If I set the Public ip for that particular EC2 instance, I have 403 Forbidden error.If I changed to default ip as 127.0.0.1, then I can access the phpmyadmin installed at my localhost not at EC2 instance. So I am curious about

(1)Why I can't access the phpmyadmin installed at EC2 instance with Public IP address of that instance.

(2)Why there is a connection or link or association between the two phpmyadmin installed at my localhost and the EC2 instance?

Thanks

Comment: Your second question makes no sense, and stems from your misunderstanding of the 127.0.0.1 address. I'd start by reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to understand that.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understood your question well.
127.0.0.1 is localhost address, if you try to access that Ip from your computer you will be accessing your own pc and everything that is installed in there: mysql, phpmyadmin, etc

For the AWS server, to access phpmyadmin from outside make sure that the security group assigned to your EC2 server has port 80 enabled from your public IP address at the inbound tab

Comment: Yes correct. For AWS server, I have security group for Http and Https from anywhere 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: You have the correct access rules, try setting a * in your phpmyadmin.conf file, that will allow access to phpmyadmin from all server interfaces